# cannot output to dat, out, or txt, but can append data to input file,

Tags: c++, fstream

first post so i hope this is not to newb of me. cannot get visual studio to create output file of any kind anywhere using cpp, but I can append the input file with my data, so i assumed my code is correct. this is what i have;

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<ostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //declarations
    string regions;
    string regionsNum;
    double qu1;
    double qu2;
    double qu3;
    double qu4;
    double average = 0.0;
    double total = 0.0;
    int regct;
    int count;
    //file declarations
    ifstream inregions;
    ofstream outregions;
    inregions.open("C:\\regions.txt", ios::in);
    if(inregions.fail() == 1)
    {
        cout << "Input failure" << endl;
        char response;
        cin.ignore(1, '\n');
        cin.get(response);
        return 1;
    }
    outregions.open("C:\\regions.dat", ios::app);
    if(outregions.fail() == 1)
    {
        cout << "Output failure" << endl;
        char response;
        cin.ignore(1, '\n');
        cin.get(response);
        return 1;
    }

    outregions << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    for(regct = 0; regct < 4; regct++)
    {

        inregions >> regions;
        inregions.ignore(1);
        inregions >> regionsNum;
        cout << regions << regionsNum << endl;
        inregions.ignore(1);
        inregions >> qu1;
        inregions.ignore(1);
        inregions >> qu2;
        inregions.ignore(1);
        inregions >> qu3;
        inregions.ignore(1);
        inregions >> qu4;

        total = qu1 + qu2 + qu3 + qu4;
        cout << total << endl;
        average = total / 4;
        outregions << regions << " " << regionsNum << " average sales $" << average << endl;
    }
    cout << "Results found in C:\\regions.txt" << endl;
    char response;
    cin.ignore(1, '\n');
    cin.get(response);

    return 0;
 }
```

I have this set up to tell me about ouput failuures after the .open, i have appended files, so i know the rest works. thanks to everyone in advance.....mrbrenzo

Comment: I've fixed your formatting. For future reference, avoid pasting tabs into the code blocks as they severely mess up the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't have permission to create/open files on `C:` .

Comment: Thanks, it is a permissions event. I am using Win7 enterprise, and it does not assume i am administrator. good call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good reference for C++ and file handling [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) Take note of the defaults on reading and writing to a file. I hope it is helpful.